# How to correct change encoding of post query?

Tags: java, tomcat, post, encoding, character-encoding

When I send post to my page without setCharacterEncoding on server-side, I get `С„С‹РІ`. With `setCharacterEncoding(UTF-8)`, I get `С‹РІР°`. How to correct change character encoding of POST query?

P.S.: I read data from ServletInputStream.

Code below.

```
doPost
req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

With getInputStream you have binary data without an encoding. Hence the binary-to-text bridging class InputStreamReader needs the correct encoding. Otherwise it uses the system default `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`.

Comment: It works. Thx. But if I read from stream directly? With `ServletInputStream.readLine` function.

Comment: Then `String line = new String(bytes, off, result, StandardardCharsets.UTF_8)`.